# BotFramework 1:1 conversation throws error "activityid can not be null"

Tags: botframework

While trying to create a 1:1 conversation using the following code, I get the error saying "activityid cannot be null" can someone please help me pointing out what is wrong?

```
 var newRecipient = new ChannelAccount();
                            newRecipient.Name = user.Mentioned.Name;
                            newRecipient.Id = user.Mentioned.Id;

                            var ConversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(activity.Recipient, newRecipient);
                            IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
                            message.From = activity.Recipient;
                            message.Recipient = newRecipient;
                            message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: ConversationId.Id);
                            message.Text = $"Congratulations {user.Mentioned.Name}!, you have got a :tangerine: from {activity.From.Name}";
                            message.Locale = "en-Us";
                            message.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
                            var reply = await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync((Activity)message);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using:

> ReplyToActivityAsync

but not replying to the existing converstation, but rather creating a new one.  You should use the following instead:

> SendToConversationAsync

Comment: Also improving the error message for the next release.

Comment: yep. That's what I eventually did. Thanks for the answer